# why handlebars compile the script template as CDATA

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, handlebars.js

I write a function which compile a handlebars template and append to the html.
I use thousands times of handlebars template in my project and all things go well.
I have to mention it'll be rendered properly in localhost, but in the server it returns me with CDATA.
but in this case handlebars outputs like this and causes lots of problems.below is template html which is inside template.php file

```
<script id="w-l-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
 <div data-name="name{{ID}}"></div>
 .....
</script>
```

here is function inside a js file called `my.js`

```
var num = 2;
function add_name(){
   var out = $('#w-l-template').html();
   var template = Handlebars.compile(out);
   var data={
     ID:num
   }
   var res=template(data);
   $('[data-main-content="main"]').append(res);
   num = num+1;
}

$(document).on('click', '#add', function(){
    add_name();
});
```

but after being rendered by handlebars, I'll get CDATA at the first line like this
`<!--[CDATA[*/<div class="col-lg-12 "data-name="2"-->`

Answer (score 0):

I know this answer is kind of late, but I had a similar issue today.  I found out that Handlebars isn't adding the CDATA into my HTML, it's actually Drupal.  We sometimes create pages with Drupal's inline editor, and so I'll drop in HTML via the Full HTML editor.

Unfortunately, if you don't configure the HTML editor in Drupal to NOT rewrite broken HTML -- it considers Handlebar script syntax as broken, then Drupal will attempt to fix the tag and add in CDATA which makes your tag get commented out.  Handlebars will then try to template that new commented tag and also output a commented out tag.   Frustrating!  But hope my answer somewhat helps you with yours (or if you run into this situation again in the future).

Basically TL:DR, it's not Handlebars -- it's probably some setting in your PHP (or CMS that uses PHP) that is probably trying to "fix" the Handlebars template because it thinks the HTML is broken.